# Asp.Net Webapi 2 Change Accounts controller base class to ODataController

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have created an asp.net webapi 2.2 project using default webapi template in Visual Studio.

By default the `AccountController` inherits from `ApiController`.

```
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
   ///
}
```

But I would like to change the base class of `AccountsController` to `OdataController` as I need to consume the service through `Odata` Protocol.

```
public class AccountController : OdataController
{
    ///
}
```

I need to perform following operations through `Odata` protocol

- Register new user
- Modify  user
- Delete User

How should I change existing  methods to support Odata .
Is there any side affects if i do this changes?
Could anyone provide me a sample code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a odata controller and add all your user handling mechanisms there. That OdataController will extend ApiController. Then the Account controller should extend your OdataController. Here is the code snippet:

```
public class OdataController: ApiController
{

}
public AccountController: OdataController
{

}
```